# Iframe Javascript bypass Same Origin policy

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I have problem with same origin policy in my webapp.
Here the situation:
I have on my server 2 vitual machine one on 80 ( apache ) and one on 880 (tomcat)
so in my webapp I have an iframe in this domain:

> http://mydomain.com:8443

ouut of iframe I have the site in this domain

> http://mydomain.com:443 (https standard)

so, if i try to comunicate with iframe javascript have a Same Orgin policy problem.

for example:

```
document.parent.myfunction();
```

return same origin problem.
There is same way to bypass this policy? 
add some header inside the Iframe and inside my main app??
thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: If you already have an apache running, why don't you use that as a reverse proxy to your tomcat? Then your javascript will always call back to the same server and port. If you don't want to do that, have a look at the [CORS header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: i recommend you EasyXdm http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/sending-and-receiving-messages/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript and same origin iframes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689984/javascript-and-same-origin-iframes)