# jQuery - grab href from click inside of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this code I got from a site. It works fine and it can detect a click inside of an iframe.

```
$('body', $('#iframeId1').contents()).click(function(event) {
 alert("Link clicked");
});
```

However, I am trying to get the href of the clicked link.
I tried :

```
var href = $(this).attr("href");
  alert(href);
```

But this alerts undefined

Comment: You need to select the link. From your limited code I am assuming that #iframe is the id of your iframe and not the id of your link; therefore, $(this) is actually in reference to the frame and not the link clicked. Console.log($(this)); to debug.

Comment: Step through your code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I need all links that are clicked.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to bind all links (a tags) in your body, you want to do something like this. This will work as expected:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  alert("Link clicked");
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  alert(href);
});
```

However, you won't be able to access or bind the contents of an iframe ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)), since that would be a huge security problem.

Comment: Iframe and parent are on my same domain. This still alerts undefined.

Comment: Why are you using an iframe then?

Comment: Does your document object say they have the same domain? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689984/javascript-and-same-origin-iframes)