# Same origin policy / CORS in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, cors, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

What is the default policy within an asp.net mvc application? Also how are CORS and X-Frame-Options related?

If I create a new MVC web app (hosted in IIS) on port e.g. 21232, I add an iframe to the index views with a source set to my local IIS e.g.

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/iisstart.htm" width="800" height="100"/>
```

This works fine (even though on a different port to the web application).

If I now change the iframe source to be something completely external, e.g.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="800" height="100"/>
```

This now displays an empty iframe. If I look in the Chrome dev tools (Chrome used in both examples) I see an error in the console

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.uk' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

1. Why did the first URL work when the address is on a different port to the hosting page?
2. How do X-Frame-Options relate to CORS? I tried adding the following to my web.config (see ref [enable cors in IIS](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html))

`<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />`

Which made no difference. Looks as if I need to add the following to the Application_Start in the global.asax.cs

```
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
```

Are X-Frame-Options specifically iframe related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got the The X-Frame-Options response header and CORS all mixed up.

The X-Frames-Options response header is used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to load a particular page in a `<iframe>`. CORS on the other hand is used to determine if XMLHttpRequest(XHR) (and a few other things) is allowed across domains.

So yes, X-Frames-Options are `<iframe>` realated only.

The reason why you are able to load your page from `http://localhost/iisstart.htm` in you web application running at port `21232` is because there is no X-Frame-Options response header present in response. You will not be able http://www.google.com because its X-Frames-Options is set to SAMEORIGIN. This means unless your domain is google.com, you will not be able load it inside an `<iframe>`.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that you added has nothing to do with `<iframe>`. There is no way you will be able to load http://www.google.com in your page.

Comment: Right OK, thanks I see and so the SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader is just to allow my website to be hosted in an iframe. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Think one source of confusion was that I wanted to access / edit iframe contents in JavaScript. As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689984/javascript-and-same-origin-iframes. Seems that here you need to adhere to the same origin policy.