# How to circumvent same origin policy error to reference elements loaded in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, same-origin-policy

There is an iframe with the following structure that is loaded via an external site `external.com` and being hosted at my domain `example.com`:

```
<body> <!-- this is the body of my html from where I'm trying to make the reference -->
    <iframe>
      #document
          <html>
              <body>      
                  <script type="text/html" id="icon-close"><div class="icon icon-close">      
                      <div class="icon icon close"</div>  
                  </script>
              </body>
          </html>
    </iframe>      
</body>
```

I'm specifically trying to select the `icon-close` element in this case.

I can select the iframe using `$("iframe")` but when I try to access the contents in inspector code to select elements using `$("iframe").contents()` I receive the following:

```
 DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 
'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin 
"https://external.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I've tried setting `domain.document = 'example.com'` before the reference:

```
 DOMException: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': 
'example.com' is not a suffix of 'external.com'.
```

I've also tried setting it to `external.com`:

```
DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 
'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com" from 
accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I've seen related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689984/javascript-and-same-origin-iframes) but don't understand exactly how to resolve this.

**How can I circumvent the same origin policy to access the elements in an iframe?**

Comment: Have you tried setting `document.domain = 'http://example.com'` (with the protocol as well)?

Comment: @ObsidianAge both `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` fail saying they `could not be parsed properly`